# How do I make simple Windows error message box in Dev-C++?

Tags: c++, windows, message, dev-c++, box

I'm trying to make Windows message box that is shown in this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I'm using latest `Dev-C++`.

My current code is this:

```
#include <windows.h>

 int DisplayResourceNAMessageBox() {
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCWSTR)L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again?",
        (LPCWSTR)L"Account Details",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2
    );

    switch (msgboxID)
    {
    case IDCANCEL:
        // TODO: add code
        break;
    case IDTRYAGAIN:
        // TODO: add code
        break;
    case IDCONTINUE:
        // TODO: add code
        break;
    }

    return msgboxID; }
```

I get bunch of errors like:

> "MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE undeclared", "IDTRYAGAIN undeclared", etc.

I'm absolute noob, what do I do?

Comment: Is windows.h found by the compiler?

Comment: I don't see any errors regarding that so I assume it is found.

Comment: Note that Dev-C++ is extremely out of date. AFAIK the last version they released was based around GCC 3.4.2. Code::Blocks with MinGW offers a much more recent compiler (GCC 4.9, and I think 5.1 is available as well).

Comment: Your errors are really strange, because MessageBox and his flags come together and windows.h contains all you need. I recommend to follow @Michael 's advise and use something modern. C::B as IDE with MinGW as compiler may be the best way to go with first steps into cross-platform development and good environments.

Comment: have you added your headers folder to dev-c? go to Tools>compiler option. and click on "add a compiler set by folder". its icon is a pluse.

Comment: FYI - vs2022 community edition is free

Answer (score 3):

Heres the code for windows.h :

```
MessageBox(NULL, "An error has occurred!", "Title!", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
```